# msxml3.dll error '80072ee2' The operation timed out

Tags: xml, rss, asp-classic, msxml, serverxmlhttp

I have a classic ASP page that is reading an external rss feed (xml document) and then displaying it on a web page. This was working fine until my website was moved to a new server. I think it is now Windows 2008. My script is now timing out. I don't think the problem is actually because it is taking too long as I have increased the time out values. does anyone know what the problem may be and how I can fix it?

The website is hosted on a shared server so I don't have much access to change any of the server settings.

The code I'm using is

```vb
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

' resolve, connect, send, receive - in milliseconds 
objhttp.setTimeouts 5000, 60000, 10000, 10000 

objHTTP.open "GET",RSSURL,false
objHTTP.send
```

The code returns the time out for the last line (objHTTP.send). "RSSURL" can be any external RSS feed. I was testing with http://www.valewisham.org.uk/rss.xml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559722/msxml3-dll-error-80072ee2-in-asp-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rarely use setTimeouts, because in most case you want an overall request timeout, try this instead:

```
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objHTTP.open "GET", RSSURL, true
objHTTP.send

objHttp.WaitForResponse 60
```

This code sets the open method third parameter to true in order to do an asynch request, then waits for the response after the send, timing out after 60 seconds