# classic asp : MSXML3 dll ServerXMLHTTP

Tags: asp-classic, msxml, msxml2, msxml3

I am using below code

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML3.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", sendstring, false
objXML.Send()
```

Its giving error on objXML.Send on **localhost** environment
I dont see any problem in this code but could not able to understand why its giving error.
I have already register successfully  dll MSXML3 using regsvr32 from location C:\wINDOWS\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll

Do I have to run proxycfg - d ?
Please advise

Please see attached error screenshot
[image]

attaching debug error

[image]

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29309967/1682881