# How to call asp page with request parameters from asp page

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to call an asp page with request parameters from an asp in my application. Both asp pages reside on the same server. I tried this with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP but it did not work. Some code is below

```
Function URLGet(URL)
  Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  Http.Open "GET",URL,True
  Http.Send
  pagestatus = Http.status
  if pagestatus<>"200" then
    URLGet="Error:"& pagestatus
  else
'   URLGet = Http.ResponseBody
    URLGet = Http.responseText
  end if
End Function
```

In this URL comes as below

```
/getchart.asp?Met=node1&SubMet=3232
```

Please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: `but did not work.` means .. are you getting any errors ?

Comment: yes at http.open it says unspecified error

Comment: can you try `/getchart.asp?Met=node1&SubMet=3232` directly in the browser ?

Comment: for this I will have to append http://localhost:109. But I have try this also but now work

Comment: so the  problem is in `getchart.asp` page ? then you should show that page code.

Comment: also, you could try with async=false `Http.Open "GET",URL,False`

Comment: no, I mean if I directly type http:/localhost:109/getchart.asp?met=node1&SubMet=3232 at browser then it give response, but at asp page it does not work

Comment: have you tried the whole path ? `http:/localhost:109/getchart.asp?met=node1&SubMet=3232` in the asp page ?

Comment: yes, i have try this also

Comment: sorry, no more bright ideas .

Comment: If you need the `responseText` you must set `async` to `False` (otherwise you'd have to add a loop waiting for the call to complete). That said, you have yet to define how exactly your code "did not work". Did you get an error message? Did you see anything in the logs?

Comment: Sounds similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5559722/249624